# Dessins d'enfants and real algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, real-algebraic-geometry, topological-graph-theory

I wrote a thesis on the Grothendieck theory of [*dessins d'enfants*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dessin_d%27enfant) (after some articles by Leila Schneps). In Shafarevich, volume 2, there's a section on real algebraic curves.

Is it possible to formulate a theory similar to that of *dessins* on real algebraic curves? If so, can you give me some reference (articles, papers or books)?

And, in general, may I formulate a theory of *dessins* on a complex manifold or on an algebraic variety of higher dimension?

Comment: Perhaps you can post this on mathoverflow? you might get some better responses there. Maybe ask a moderator to move it over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are still interested by the subject. Real dessins d'enfant is a really interesting subject, and first introduced in [this article](https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~orevkov/c79.pdf).

The idea is simple : instad of looking the preimage of $[0,1]$, one should look at the preimage of $\mathbb RP^1$, and putting extra "real" decoration.

A full book on the subject is [here](https://www.degruyter.com/view/product/129377) with lot of informations and applications. Real dessin d'enfants can give lot of informations about singular curves (computation of their fundamental group), and also Lefschetz fibrations.